# how to recieve auto generated array as post variable

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have tried this simple code to generate an array which will send and a form data in post method. what is the way of receiving this array in desired page? Here is the code:

```
 $serial = 0;foreach ($results as $row) {$serial = $serial + 1;
```

Html:

```
<input class="float-lt" type="radio" value=""; ?>" name="question-<?php echo "{$serial}"; ?>[]"/>
<input class="float-lt" type="radio" value=""; ?>" name="question-<?php echo "{$serial}"; ?>[]"/>
```

Comment: can we see more of the code please? as it stands at the moment its impossible to tell what youre trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask. Please post the exact and final markup as created by your php code (use your brwosers feature to show the source of the loaded page). Also please add a dump of the `$_POST` superglobal variable in the processing php script.

Comment: You could create and additional array with all serials and on the server loop over the serials array to get the wanted arrays:

Answer (score 0):

```
$used_serials = $_POST['serials];
foreach( $used_serials AS &$serial ){
    $key = 'question-'.$serial;
    $wanted_serial_pack = $_POST[$key];
}
```

OR better use an multidimensional Array structure like:

```
name="question['serials'][$serial]"
```

Then you can loop over $_POST['serials]

Comment: <form class="" action="modeltest_result.php" method="post">
 <?php   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { $active = 0;                         $inactive = 0; $serial = 0; $sql = "SELECT * from questions order by rand() limit 2"; $query = $db->query($sql);                                        $results = $query->fetchAll();} if ($db->affected_rows() > 0) {        foreach ($results as $row) {$serial = $serial + 1;?>

Comment: <div><span><?php echo "{$serial}"; ?></span><h4><?php echo "{$row->question}"; ?></h4><input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="<?php echo "{$row->id}"; ?>"/></div>                                      <div class="clear"></div>  <div class="col span_1_of_2">
<div class=""> <input class="float-lt" type="radio" value="<?php echo "{$row->option_A}"; ?>" name="question-<?php echo "{$serial}"; ?>[]"/>
 <div class="title-desc"><p><?php echo "{$row->option_A}"; ?></p></div><div class="clear"></div> </div></div>

Comment: <div class="col span_1_of_2"><div class=""><input class="float-lt" type="radio" value="<?php echo "{$row->option_B}"; ?>" name="question-<?php echo "{$serial}"; ?>[]"/><div class="title-desc"><p><?php echo "{$row->option_B}"; ?></p></div><div class="clear"></div> 
 </div>   </form>

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
$serial = 0;
$inputs = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $serial = $serial + 1;
    $inputs[] = "<input name=\"question['keys']['{$serial}'][]\"/>";
}
```

template.php:

```
echo implode(' ',$inputs);
```

Submit.php

```
$results = $_POST['keys];
foreach($results as $serial_array){
    var_dump($serial_array);
}
```

Something like this may help.